# How to enable syntax highlighting in Eclipse Indigo?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

How to enable syntax highlighting in Eclipe Indigo? I write in Java. I installed [this plugins](http://www.hawksley.net/wp/2009/08/using-eclipse-on-small-screens/) for more comfortable usage on small screens, but even if I turn it off - all the words in editor are black:(

Comment: What editor is it using? Have you checked in `Preferences -> General -> Editors -> File Associations`?

Comment: @arturo there are "Java Editor" is associated with `.java` files...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you are using the Java perspective (or Java EE) as well. You should be able to see the name of the active perspective and/or editor in the title bar.

To be 100% sure, you can always right click on the file in question and Open With->Java Editor to ensure that it is the Java editor that is open for your file.

Comment: Thanks! I changed default editor when read @arturo's comment but document was still opened it WindowBuilder's editor.

Answer (score 1):

You may set your coloring preferences by

Window->Preferences-> Java->Editor->Syntax Coloring

Comment: Preview there shows that it should be colored, but it is not.

Comment: Can you verify if the project is a Java project? Also, please post a screen shot of the "syntax Coloring" section?

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse remembers which editor you last used to open a file and keeps opening it with that editor, even if you've installed a better one later.  Right-click on the file and force it to open with the Java Editor using the "Open With..." menu.  If you're not getting *any* coloring at all, you might just be using the wrong editor.

[image]